# SOLID principles and web page class

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, design-patterns, solid-principles

I am trying to follow SOLID principles when writing new classes and code.

My question is about ASP.NET classes that extend the Page class i.e. ASPX files.  If I had a page class that has a page_load event that creates instances of multiple objects e.g. Person class, Sport class etc then I believe this page class is tightly coupled with these classes.  Is this the case or am I missing something obvious? Could it be that all classes should expose interfaces and the client (aspx pages) should use the interfaces rather than instantiating the classes directly.

I find interfaces useful if Polymorphism is involved e.g. using a Student interface to create an instance of graduate or undergraduate at runtime.  Should all classes have interfaces?

Comment: SOLID principles? as in ? all classes should expose interfaces and the client (aspx pages) should use the interfaces rather than instantiating the classes directly.      THIS IS IN NO WAY SOLID

Comment: @Zia, SOLID principles are described here: (http://www.remondo.net/solid-principles-csharp-interface-segregation/

Comment: @Zia, I didn't say it was.  I said I am trying to follow SOLID principles and I have a question about the Page class.

Comment: well thanks for the link

Comment: @Zia, could you explain why "THIS IS IN NO WAY SOLID"

Comment: sorry busy right now , will get back to u later

Answer (score 1):

If you create your entities inside your `Page` class (presentation layer), you are clearly violating the Single Responsibility Principle, since the page class will have multiple reasons to change.

Instead, move this logic to the business layer and create a service that handles this logic.

Your page will need to talk to the service interface, not the implementation (DIP) and this service interface needs to be narrow (ISP); probably just have one method.

If you package all arguments for the service into a single object, thus separating data and behavior, and use a generic interface for your services (i.e. `ICommandHandler<TCommand>`), you can even comply to the OCP, since you can now add behavior (such as validation, transactions, deadlock detection, asynchronous processing, queueing) to services, whithout any changes to the application.

Last note, don't create interfaces for entities. This is rather useless, and obscures your code.

Comment: Thanks.  The web application in question is very large with many pages.  Can you recommend a design pattern or forward me to a web page that confirms this?

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91

Comment: Thanks but I don't see any reference to a page class in this link.

Comment: The article describes the command/handler pattern, which is an important pattern when applying the SOLID principles. Another pattern to look at wheb working with ASP.NET Page classes is the Model View Presenter pattern.

Comment: Which pattern do you think is better? I suppose it depends on the scenario.

Comment: MVP is a Presentation Layer pattern while command/handler is used at the Business Layer, so they're not mutually exclusive. MVP , MVC , and MVVP, are mutually exclusive (sort of), so investigate in picking the right PL pattern. And investigate in picking the right BL pattern; Command/Handler is a BL pattern I often use.

Comment: I have looked at an example of MVP here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14642/Model-View-Presenter-with-ASP-NET.  Surely this is not good as an instance of the presenter is created in the code behind.

Comment: @Steven What defines a 'entity' in your reference to it, above?

Comment: A `Person` and `Sport` class would be entities (business objects) in your case.

Comment: @Steven. You refer to avoid separation as kind of ISportRepository  and ISportRepository on a separation of data source? Or the more common, speak of Entity as a object from Entity Framework? I'm just curious,

Comment: Entity is a common term. Business objects is another term, they mean about the same. So yes, it's an entity as in 'Entity Framework', but it doesn't mean you have to use EF. An entity is just an representation of an element for the business your software tries to automate. I'm not sure I understand your question about separation of data source.

Comment: @Steven, do you separate the BLL with the command/handler pattern.  How does this compare to a tiered approach described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712184/net-design-patterns-tiers.  I am nearly at the point of marking this question answered.

Comment: @Steven I'm fine with that. Thank's for borrow time to comments. I have a Q here; http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/158134/20636 which ask for how this terms are used.

Comment: @Jonas: I agree with the ansers given to that question.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't instantiate the objects in the code behind.  What I do is call a service that instantiates gets the objects - which instantiates them with data from the database.  I also made the service public in a masterpage and reference it like this:

```
IUser _user = (Page.Master as MasterBase).RegistrationService.GetPersonFromEmailAddress(txtUser.text);
```

of course you should check to make sure (Page.Master as MasterBase) isn't null....

---

### Edit by request

I create a base Master Page that all other site Master Pages must inherit from.  In constructor of this base Master Page I instantiate all of the services that are necessary.  Of course, if the services aren't used through-out the site, they can be instantiated on a different, more appropriate section-general Master page.

```
public readonly IRegistration RegistrationService;
public readonly IEventService EventService;
public readonly IEmailSendingService EmailService;
private readonly IMenuService _menuService;

public MasterBase()
{
    RegistrationService = new BusinessLogic.Registration(DatabaseConnectionString);
    EventService = new EventService(DatabaseConnectionString);

    var fromAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Webmaster"];
    var defaultToEmailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["toEmail"];
    EmailService = new EmailSendingService(BaseUrl, fromAddress, defaultEmailAddress);
    _menuService = new MenuService(DatabaseConnectionString);
}
```

As mentioned above, any Master Pages used on the site will inherit from the base:

```
public partial class MasterContent : MasterBase
```

Any UI page that references a Master Page (just about all of them in my case)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="activities.aspx.cs" Inherits="activities" MasterPageFile="~/MasterContent.Master" %>
```

will now have access to the different services in the code behind:

```
IUser _user = (Page.Master as MasterBase).RegistrationService.GetPersonFromEmailAddress(txtUser.text);
```

As mentioned in the comments below, the different UI pages do have a tight coupling with the Base Master Page, but I don't know of any better way to do it in a general ASP.NET web forms application.  It alleviates the need to instantiate the service on every UI page, and from a project-specific perspective, it is acceptable to make all Master Pages inherit from this base page.

Comment: So basically you advocate using global scope. You are creating a very tight coupling that way between pages and master pages. A coupling that does not need to exist

Comment: @RuneFS I agree, it does create a tight coupling, but I somewhat alleviate the tightness by creating a Base MasterPage that all site MasterPages inherit from.  For this particular project, any new Master pages will have to inherit it, so they will have access to the RegistrationService.  The only alternative that I see is to find a way to inject the service dependency into every System.Web.UI.Page that needs the service.  I haven't found a good way of doing this in ASP.NET (MVC is a different story, but not general Web Forms)  How do you suggest it to be done?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this was to configure your dependencies in the Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Create/{Service}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx",{"Service", new WhatEverSErvice()} );
}
```

Where you'd need to fit the URL pattern and file path to suite your site. This will give you a handle to a service object through the Service route value

You could then declare a base page class

```
public abstract class BasePage<TService> : Page where TService : IService {

   protected TService Service{
       get {
           return Page.RouteData.Values["Service"] as TService;
       }
   }
}
```

Here `IService` is an interface you will have to define that's the basis for your services (if such an interface makes sense otherwise simply omit the where clause)

Then have all your pages derive from this class and when ever you need your particular service you simply write something like

```
var myFoo = Service.CreateFoo();
```

This approach does act somewhat strange in error scenarios when the user supplies a string after the /. You could handle this by extending the property, since it's basically a file not found (The supplied URL is invalid) you could return a 404 FNF response