# .NET Design Patterns (tiers)

Tags: asp.net, .net, design-patterns

I support and develop a large ASP.NET application (I am a sole developer).  I am trying to adopt a structured approach to coding by using design patterns, but I have not yet managed to grasp the subject fully.  I was thinking about using a MVP pattern for the user interface and a data tier to separate the business logic and the data logic (two patterns in total).  For example, have a look at the code below:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private _ConString As String

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            If Session("OrderID") > " " Then 'Line 10
            Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
                _ConString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnection").ConnectionString
                Dim objCon As New SqlConnection(_ConString)
                Dim objCommand As New SqlCommand
                objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ID = " & session("id") 'I know this could cause SQL injection attacks.  I wrote it quickly to get my point accross
                objCon.Open()
                objCommand.Connection = objCon
                objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader
                Do While objDR.Read
                    MsgBox(objDR("name"))
                Loop
                objDR.Close()
    End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

This breaks a lot of SOLID rules.  There is data logic and business logic in the presentation layer (line 10 is the business logic).

I was thinking about creating two new classes i.e. PersonDAL (for the data access layer) and PersonBLL for the business logic layer.  The business logic layer and the data access layer will have the same function names i.e. getPerson() i.e. the presentation layer will call getPerson in the BLL layer which will call getPerson in the DAL.  My question is: is this a good apprach or is there a better way to break up this function into tiers?

I have looked at the following link, which talks about this approach when using datasets, but I am not using datasets i.e. I am using SQLCommands and SQLDataReaders: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581779.aspx.

Comment: What is the function `session("ID")` returning? If it is not a int you may have a sql injection attack on your hands. You should be using parameters.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, thanks.  I use parametrized queries in the live system to avoid SQL injection attacks.  I wrote the code above quickly for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 1):

We have applications that have been in production for 8+ years using this exact tier structure, designed initially based on Microsoft reference applications.

This tiered system has allowed us to easily add web client, service interfaces (for processing incoming email), win forms clients, windows tablet clients, and most recently support an almost direct port to mono for creation of iPad clients.

All of the clients share the BLL and communicate with the DAL through .Net remoting or WCF. This approach also allows us to distribute the web client and DAL across multiple physical servers in order to handle very large numbers of users.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have a one to one relationship between classes in the Business Logic Layer and the Data Logic Layer? For example, if you had a class (StudentBLL) and another class that inherits from Student (UndergraduateBLL) then would you always have two data logic classes i.e. StudentDLL and UndergraduateDLL even if undergraduateBLL only needed to use functions in StudentDLL.

Comment: No, our data access layer is actually somewhat generic. We have classes that are responsible for various logical sections of the application (i.e. ListSystem for list-related activities) and these sections contain methods specific to that area. And most of the methods in the DAL are fairly small since we rely heavily on reflection to automatically move data into and out of the database. Our rule is that any class property that is stored in the database must have the same name as the column in the database. That way we can have a single line of code to move an entire class into or out of tables

Comment: Thanks. Is it fair to say that your DAL has an independent structure ie independent of the dal? Do you have inheritance and polymorphism in the dal?

Comment: The classes that comprise the DAL only use inheritance and polymorphism in a limited fashion (primarily to abstract the database interface; we have to support SQL Server, Oracle, Microsoft Access, SQLCE, and Sqlite). However, the BLL, which the DAL consumes, uses I&P extensively.

Comment: Is it fair to say that you divorce the layers to support a large number of users and a large number of clients? I don't have this requirement. I am trying to make the code more readable and scaleable. I don't want to waste time though.

Comment: That is one benefit to this approach; the other benefit is the ability to quickly add new user interface client types (or views in existing ones) without having duplicate code spread throughout. And once we started writing applications this way, it is very, very difficult to go back to a monolithic application approach (it just never "feels" like the right approach). One of the primary reasons that we use .Net remoting is that if we need to deliver a single executable, it is trivial to have all of the layers in a single application (they are just different projects).

Comment: Finally could you confirm how you "use reflection to move data in and out of the database"

Comment: Sure: when we read data from a DbDataReader, we loop through the columns that are returned. We then use reflection to find the corresponding property in the class. Then we loop through the data rows and use PropertyInfo.SetValue to move the data from the reader into the Property. For to database we use stored procedures. We get the list of parameters from the stored procedure, find the property in the class, and use PropertyInfo.GetValue to move the value from the property to the stored proc parameter and once proc is executed, we move output parameter values back into properties.

Comment: Is there a name for the pattern of using "reflection to find the corresponding property in the class"?